# Cambio de paginas después de paginación

Tags: php

Estoy creando una paginación y funciona, me trae todos los valores que le pido pero cuando quiero cambiar de pagina no se formatea la url.

Al momento de comenzar a hacer la navegación con la paginación, todos los datos salen como quiero y en la URL se imprime como debería.

```
http://localhost/FrontEnd/personas/1
```

Pero cuando intento cambiar de pagina (o vista, como mejor se entienda) en la URL me aparece lo siguiente:

```
http://localhost/FrontEnd/personas/contacto
```

y por obvias razones no entra a la pagina de contacto ya que en la url deberia aparecer como

```
http://localhost/FrontEnd/personas/contacto
```

> Mandar a llamar las paginas

```
$rutas = array();
$ruta = null;
$infoUsuario = null;

if (isset($_GET["ruta"])) {
    $rutas = explode("/", $_GET["ruta"]);

    $valor =  $rutas[0];

    $rutaUsuarios = $consulta;


    if($rutas[0] == $rutaUsuarios["nickname"]){

        $infoUsuario = $rutas[0];

    }

    if($infoUsuario != null){

       include 'modulos/info.php';

    }  else if ($rutas[0] == "pagina1" || $rutas[0] == "pagina2" || $rutas[0] == "personas" || $rutas[0] == "pagina4" || $rutas[0] == "pagina5" || $rutas[0] == "pagina6" ||  $rutas[0] == "pagina7" || $rutas[0] == "salir" || $rutas[0] == "pagina9" || $rutas[0] == "contacto" || $rutas[0] == "pagina11" || $rutas[0] == "pagina12" || $rutas[0] == "pagina13"  || $rutas[0] == "pagina14"){

        include "modulos/".$rutas[0].".php";

    }else if($rutas[0] == "" || $rutas[0] == "inicio"){

        include "modulos/inicio.php";

    } else {
        include "modulos/error404.php";
    }
} else {
    include "modulos/inicio.php";
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir tu código ?

Comment: @LucianoMontañez el de la paginacion?

Comment: Tu configuración de routing.

Comment: @LucianoMontañez listo